# If $f$ is absolutely continuous then $PV(f,[a,b])=\int_{[a,b]}(f')^+$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$.  Define $PV(f,[a,b])$ to be the positive variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$.  I need to show that $PV(f,[a,b])=\int_{[a,b]}(f')^+$.  I've already shown that $TV(f,[a,b])=\int_{[a,b]} |f'|$ where $TV$ denotes the total variation.  We'll also denote $NV$ as the negative variation, and we know $TV=PV+NV$.  Here's what I've tried so far:

$$ TV(f,[a,b])=\int_{[a,b]} |f'| = PV(f,[a,b])+NV(f,[a,b]) = \int_{[a,b]}(f')^+ + \int_{[a,b]}(f')^- $$

I also know that $f'=(f')^+-(f')^-$ and so $\int_{[a,b]} f' = \int_{[a,b]} (f')^+-\int_{[a,b]}(f')^-$.  It seems like a relationship between $\int_{[a,b]} f'$ and the variation would be productive.  But the only one that I know is $\int_{[a,b]} f' \le f(b)-f(a)$.  If I had equality then I could use this together with $TV(f,[a,b])=f(b)-f(a)$ but I'm not certain that the reverse inequality holds.  In fact I have a theorem saying that absolute continuity is equivalent to this equality only under the hypothesis that $f'$ is monotonic.  Since that may not be true here, then I suspect the equality does not necessarily hold.

Comment: The equality in question is the fundamental theorem of calculus for AC functions. It doesn't require $f$ to be monotonic.